# Tkinter: AttributeError: module 'X' has no attribute 'Y'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to create an app to score a questionnaire. To avoid circular referencing I have 3 (really 4 but one is not required as part of the MWE) files or modules (If I am correct). 
1) `Main.py`; 2) `scoring.py`; 3) `variables.py` (to avoid circular referencing). All I need to do is print the variable dvQ1 using the button in `main.py` so perhaps this code is far too complex for what I need.

Basically, all I would like to do is score and print the scores of the entries (the list of the questions (`Q1list`) is in a different file, and I don't think needed for a MWE). I am trying my best to use different files to have cleanly organized code as there will be 20-32 questions.

```
main.py
from tkinter import *
import variables as var

Label(win, text="X, Y, Z text", justify = LEFT, wraplength=500 ).grid(row=3, columnspan=2)
q1 = IntVar()
for text, value in Q1list:
    b = Radiobutton(win, text=text, variable=q1, value=value)
    b.grid(sticky='W', rowspan=5, columnspan=2)

def print_button():
sc = var.Score()
print(sc.Q1score)
```

The scoring.py file is simply to create the `dvQ1` variable that will be passed to the `variables.py` file. The circular relationship would have occurred when I imported the variable `q1` from `main.py' and then imported the final variable dvQ1 or Q1score from`scoring.py` into main to then print. This is why I added the 'variables.py' file.

```
scoring.py
from main import *

Q1 = q1.get()
if Q1 == 1:
    dvQ1 = 0
elif Q1 == 2:
    dvQ1 = 0.873
elif Q1 == 3:
    dvQ1 = 0.237
elif Q1 == 4:
    dvQ1 = 0.86
elif Q1 == 5:
    dvQ1 = 1
else:
    dvQ1 = np.NaN
```

This last file I am trying to build my class to allow the variables to be "seen" within the main window in main.py. I really just want to set a variable (Q1score, or just dvQ1) to send over to `main.py'.

```
variables.py    
from tkinter import *
import numpy as np
import scoring

class Score:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Q1score = IntVar()
        self.Q1score.set(scoring.dvQ1)
        return(Q1score)
```

I keep getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/nrsmoll/PycharmProjects/SeaOfScores/main.py", line 61, in print_button
    sc = var.Score()
AttributeError: module 'variables' has no attribute 'Score'
```

Comment: when you `import scoring` in *variables.py* , it's also executing `from main import *` ...you are facing a circular import

Comment: Have you tried `sc = var.get()`?

Comment: Good thought, I tried `sc = var.get()` and `sc = var.get(Q1score)` in `main.py` but get the `AttributeError: module 'variables' has no attribute 'get'`. If I try to `.get()` the variable from `scoring.py` I become circular. I tried removing the circularity from @PRMoureu 's suggestion to no avail. I'm sure there is a simpler way to do what I am trying to do.